# SpringBoot, Keycloak adapter, Kubernetes: Failed to load URLs from pod.namespace

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-security, keycloak

I am using the keycloak adapter for springboot to manage the authentication.
In localhost it works well with an URL for Keycloak like "https://kc.dev.com/auth"
But when I deploy the app in Kubernetes cluster, the Keycloak adapter cannot reach the keycloak server because of the URL I configured "service.namespace:port/auth"
It doesn't work here, even with the http client feign it is working for another need.

If someone knows how to fix it...
Please let me know